# Image Editors for Programmers?

Tags: windows, macos

This is not technically a programming question, but I believe its still relevant to software developers.

My question is: What image editors are there that are targeted at programmers. Specifically editors with the features that the older generation of image editors had. Modern image editors (such as The Gimp) seem to abstract away the vagaries of each image format.

A programmers editor would let one:

- Set the index of the transparent color when working with formats like GIF.
- View and edit the color table for palletized formats.
- (obviously) load and save a wide variety of formats (gif, png, tiff, pcx, bmp, jpeg, ico etc.) without loosing any metadata relevant to the format.
- view and edit of said metadata.
- work with multiframe (animated gif) or multi image (ico) formats.
- edit the alpha channel for image formats with alpha.

Do such beasts no longer exist?

Answer (score 2):

I use Gimp for such purposes...
The only trouble with it - it is uncomfortable with ico files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with a command-line interface, I think you can do all the above with ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick.

Answer (score 0):

[Paint.Net](http://www.getpaint.net) for Windows or [Pinta](http://pinta-project.com/) for most platforms, not as complicated as Gimp or Photoshiop but with enough features.